# Actionscript 3.0 Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller

Tags: actionscript-3, displaylist

I have a warning about this:

> ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child
>   of the caller. at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
>   I don't what is wrong with the code.

```
public function Laser() {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You add laser to the stage, so remove it also from the stage.

```
if(lasers[l].y < 0) 
{

    stage.removeChild(lasers[l]); // <- Here
    lasers[l] = null;
    lasers.splice(l, 1);
    trace("Remove laser from screen");

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. But if i should make hitTestobject can i write this: if(lasers[l].hitTestObject(enemiesArray[e]))
{
 this.parent.removeChild(enemiesArray[e]);
}

Comment: You can, but be aware with `this.parent`, It must be really parent for enemies. Such approach is more secure: `var enemy: DisplayObject = enemiesArray[e]; enemy.parent.removeChild(enemy)`